# Calling bash script as Python subprocess - Bash falls into endless loop getting bad input

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, shell

I'm using Python 2.7 with Glade 3.15 to create a GUI that allows click-button execution of a variety of existing bash/cshell scripts maintained by my work team.  I'm fairly new to Python, but have managed to get the basic application structure up-and-running.  However, certain bash scripts I'm calling will step through multiple user prompts and take input to determine end behavior.  The problem I am encountering is when I call a bash script as a python subprocess, the bash script appears to take a null input over-and-over, thus causing the prompts to loop endlessly.

For example:
A bash script that prompts:

```
"Please enter your 4 digit document number:"
  ** accept user input in terminal **
"You entered ----, is that correct?
       1.) Yes
       2.) No "
```

When called from python, the terminal will press through the the prompts, sending an empty response.  Since the bash script loops until affirmative response is received, the result is a terminal endlessly printing:

```
"You entered ----, is that correct?
         1.) Yes
         2.) No "
```

I've tried extensively to find answers, here and elsewhere, regarding this issue, but have not found/developed a solution yet.

My basic python, relative to this problem, is as follows (although I have tried a wide variety of different approaches)

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
...
# Definition for subprocess calls
  def subprocess_cmd(self, command):
     process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   
     process.wait()
     (output, err) = process.communicate()
     print output
...

# Script-Call Button
  def on_btnScript_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    self.subprocess_cmd("scriptname_is_here")
```

I just want to call a subprocess from my python button_click event that kicks-off the bash script in the terminal, and waits for keyboard terminal input to walk-through the prompts, as it would if it were run directly from terminal.  Sorry so long - wanted to be thorough and explicit. Thanks in advance for any help.

*****UPDATE****

If I call the subprocess from another standalone python file with the .wait() method, the interaction works as desired.  But, when I call the subprocess as a result of the GUI button_click event, with the same arguments and methods, the looping anomaly happens. I think this has to do with my button click event and subprocess_cmd 'function' being defined in my mainDialog class, but I don't know how to separate them while retaining my connection to GUI.

Here is more context for my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Library Imports
from gi.repository import Gtk
from os import system
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import time
try:
  import math
except:
   print "Math Library Missing"
   sys.exit(1)

class mainDialog:

# Build the 'form load' parameters
  def __init__(self):
    self.gladefile = "test.glade"
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)
    self.winMain = self.builder.get_object("winMain")
    self.winCptArg = self.builder.get_object("winCptArg")
    self.winMsbHelp = self.builder.get_object("winMsbHelp")
    self.winCptHelp = self.builder.get_object("winCptHelp")
    self.winAiHelp = self.builder.get_object("winAiHelp")
    self.winMain.move(2625, 400)
    self.winMain.show()

# Definition for subprocess calls
  def subprocess_cmd(self, command):
     process = subprocess.Popen(command)   
     process.wait()
...

# Script-Call Button
  def on_btnScript_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    self.subprocess_cmd("scriptname_is_here")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main = mainDialog()
  Gtk.main()
```

Comment: `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` means that the subprocess should get its input from the pipe, not from the terminal.

Comment: You have configured your `Popen` call with `stdin=Subprocess.PIPE`. This won't allow to accept any input.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense, and I appreciate you clarifying.  Can you explain what I should set stdin to to receive terminal input?  I have tried stdin=None, which doesn't work, as well as not defining stdin at all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `os.system`:

```
from os import system
...
# Definition for subprocess calls
def subprocess_cmd(self, command):
    process = system(str(command))
...
# Script-Call Button
def on_btnScript_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    self.os.system("echo scriptname_is_here")
```

The syntax is `os.system("executable option parameter")`.
For example,

```
os.system("ls -al /home")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This does seem to achieve the basic functionality I was looking for, but I can't figure out how to pass an argument through this call -- any advice?

Comment: I added the syntax for what you asked

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone is interested, to achieve what I was intending, I simply left stdin and stdout alone, and applied the .wait() method to the subprocess definition -- but this only works when called from a standalone python script; I haven't been able to retain functionality when connected to GUI button click event.

```
 def subprocess_cmd(self, command):
     process = subprocess.Popen(command).wait() 
...

 def on_btnScript_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    self.subprocess_cmd("filepath/scriptname_is_here")
```

stdin and stdout can be left as default, and standard terminal interaction can be achieved, so long as the subprocess definition is appended with the wait() method.